# terminal for loop dealing with spaces and newlines

Tags: for-loop, terminal, escaping

So on OSX, I run:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices | tail -n +2
```

which for example gives:

```
Built-in Ethernet
Wi-Fi
Thunderbolt Ethernet
iPhone USB
```

if I run:

```
for n in $(networksetup -listallnetworkservices | tail -n +2); do echo $n; done
```

I get:

```
Built-in
Ethernet
Wi-Fi
Thunderbolt
Ethernet
iPhone
USB
```

Which is no good as the for command is replacing spaces with newlines. So, if I add quotes and run:

```
for n in "$(networksetup -listallnetworkservices | tail -n +2)"; do echo $n; done
```

I get no newlines at all...

```
Built-in Ethernet Wi-Fi Thunderbolt Ethernet iPhone USB
```

Anyone know how to get the list to output the original syntax? I want to script the output to switch off the IPv6 stack, by replacing the echo command with:

```
sudo networksetup -setv6off "$n";
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops iterate over elements delimited by whitespace as defined in the `IFS` variable. You can remove the space character as follows:

```
( IFS=''; for f in `networksetup -listallnetworkservices | tail -n +2`;do echo $f;done )
```

A better choice might be to use a `while` loop:

```
networksetup -listallnetworkservices | tail -n +2 | while read f; do echo $f; done
```

Running `help read` will introduce you to a whole new set of possibilities in shell scripting.